# ¿Cómo referenciar funciones de archivos JS en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy migrando un pequeño proyecto a react. Es un HTML estático que presenta los archivos `html`, `css` y `js`. Tengo un problema al llamar las funcionalidades que tenía en mis `js`, no sé como importarlas o hacer referencias al elemento (porque se referenciaban con getElementById). Alguien tendrá una idea de como relacionarlo o incluirlos porque es la lógica de la página. Aquí les dejo una parte de mi proyecto:

mi archivo JS:

```
aparecer = function() {
    var soc = document.getElementById('social')
    soc.style.display = "block";
};
desaparecer = function() {
    var soc = document.getElementById('social')
    soc.style.display = "none";
};
```

El archivo ya en react al cual quiero agregarle dicha funcionalidad:

```
import React from "react";
import board from '../../img/menuLeft/board.png';
import puzzle from '../../img/menuLeft/puzzle.png';
import cat from '../../img/menuLeft/cat.png';

// style
import './MenuLeft.css'

function MenuLeft(){
    return(
        <>
        <div id="focussocial"
        //   className="socialfocus"
        //   onMouseOver="aparecer()" 
        //   onMouseOut="desaparecer()"
        ></div>
        <div id="social"
        //   className="social" 
        //   onMouseOut="desaparecer()" 
        //   onMouseOver="aparecer()"
          >
            <ul style={{paddingLeft: '0px'}}>
                <li>
                    <a href="/command/pizarra/?cod=<%= codigoClase %>" className="icon-facebook"><img src={board} width="40"/>
                        <p className="text-menu-left">PIZARRA</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/command/blockly/?cod=<%= codigoClase %>" className="icon-twitter" ><img src={puzzle} width="40" />
                        <p className="text-menu-left">BLOCKY</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" className="icon-googleplus"><img src={cat} width="40" />
                        <p className="text-menu-left">SCRATCH</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </> 
)
}

export default MenuLeft;
```

El código comentado eran las funciones como se hacían referencia cuando era solo `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `react` puedes simplemente usar el `state` para ese tipo de tareas, te dejaré un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function MenuLeft() {
  const [ isVisible, setIsVisible ] = useState(false);

  return <>
    {/** Tu código **/}
    {
       isVisible && <div id="social">
         {/** Tu código **/}
       </div>
    }
  </>
}
```

Como puedes observar, hice algunas cosas importantes a tener en cuenta, te paso a explicar:

- Importar el `useState`, porque esta función de React nos permite generar un variable de estado, y en dicha variable es donde vamos a definir si el botón debería mostrarse o no. Al llamar a `useState` nos devuelve un Array con 2 elementos, el primero es el valor que necesitamos y el segundo es una función para setear ese valor de forma reactiva. Para nuestro ejemplo como definimos `useState(false)` entonces `isVisible` tiene un valor igual a `false`, para volverlo `true` entonces debemos llamar a `setIsVisible(true)`
- Otro elemento importante es la desestructuración de los objetos, esto básicamente es una forma de asignar variables en el ejemplo, es decir, si definimos una constante llamada `array = ['foo', 'bar']` entonces al desestructurarlo podemos hacerlo así `const [ var1, var2 ] = array` y si luego verificamos sus valores vemos que `console.log(var1)` arroja `foo`. Eso tal cual hago con el `useState`
- Como puedes observar envolví el `div` entre unos `{}` porque esta es la forma de ejecutar javascript dentro de `.jsx`.
- Dentro del bloque donde puedo ejecutar javascript, evalúo si `isVisible` es verdadero. Cuando se utiliza la estructura `&&` quiere decir que lo que siga después de esa estructura se evalúa, de lo contrario evalúa a `null` por lo que anteponer el `isVisible && <div...` a tu div hará que este solo se muestre cuando esté visible

Ya lo próximo a tener en cuenta es que para poder cambiar el valor de `isVisible` necesitas un elemento que accione, como no sé en tu caso cual es el elemento o la acción que hace que se muestre o no el div, entonces te pondré un ejemplo con un botón de cómo deberías setear el valor:

```
<button onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>Mostrar/Ocultar</button>
```

De esta forma cuando hagan click al botón (accionador) va a causar que se renderice de nuevo el componente y ahora `isVisible` será igual a `true`, y cada vez que lo presiones irá alternando su valor de `true` a `false` ya que siempre estamos seteando el valor inverso al colocar el `!`, lo que se conoce como un `toggle`.

Espero haberte ayudado, y cualquier pregunta comenta.

Comment: Si funciona amigo gracias! Pero tengo dos dudas aún, si es que tengo que agregar más funciones JS, ¿tendría que estar agregando en el `state` al componente e ir cambiando o modificando de la misma manera como me enseñaste? y lo otro es: ¿Como puedo referenciar un elemento para trabajar con él? Así como en `js` a través del `getElementById` para el DOM. ¿En React hay alguna manera?. Gracias de antemano :D